# Regular expression for empty space only on first place?

Tags: regex

I'm using this regular expression to check if character is letter on first place :

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$)
```

But i dont know how to modified to check if its empty space on first place any suggestion?

Comment: Please edit the question by adding a couple of sample inputs and expected outputs. Also, as the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding \s should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s](?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$)
```

Answer (score 0):

`\s` denotes a whitespace in regex, so, assuming you want to check the first character is a whitespace instead of a letter:

```
^\s(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$)
```